# Find value from one UserControl to anoter Usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page in that Page I have **2 usercontrols uc1 and uc2**
I have one property **PageID** on the **Usercontrol uc1**, now I have a button on uc1 on that button's click event I am doing some database process and that will return the PageID, now I want to access this PageID on another Usercontrol uc2.

any one please help me to find out the PageID on another usercontrol

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you having difficulties? Show us your current code and where the problems are.

Comment: Please answer the questions. You did not provide nearly enough information for anyone to be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution...

Create a method on your page that takes in PageID.

```
public void MyMethod(int pageID) { ... }
```

In your button click event, do your DB lookup, then call the method...

```
public void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var pageID = MyDal.Instance.GetPageID(someParam);
     this.MyMethod(pageID);
}
```

My Method can then invoke a method on UC2, or it can just set a value.  Whatever you need.

There are certainly more scalable ways to do this that don't use so much coupling, but this will do the trick quickly.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just create a field or property on your page and make it accessible to both controls...one will set it and the other will consume it.

Answer (score 0):

```
((UserControl1)Page.FindControl("usercontrol1Id)).PageID
```

But this is dirty way. Rather raise an event from UC1 when processing is done, and let page capture it. Once page has the event, page can call method in UC2 passing the UC1 page id.